# How to fix 'invalid_client' error with Oauth 2.0 in node.js

Tags: node.js, oauth, bexio

I am trying to get access to the Bexio API with Oauth 2.0. I am trying to implement this on a node.js server. The first step(getting an access code) is working and my callback method is executed. Getting an access token always failed however. When I do a post request to  get an access token I always get an 'invalid_client' error with description 'Client credentials were not found in the headers or body'.

I have a client Id and secret and I managed to get an access token using postman, so obviously the error is in my code. Someone suggested that I need to encode the body of the request (and there could be stuff like '=' in the client secret) but I could not find much information about that.

This is the code I have:

```
let redirect_uri =
  process.env.REDIRECT_URI ||
  'http://localhost:8888/callback'

app.get('/login', function(req, res) {
  res.redirect('https://office.bexio.com/oauth/authorize?' +
    querystring.stringify({
      response_type: 'code',
      client_id: CLIENT_ID,
      scope: 'contact_edit monitoring_show',
      state: 'abc',
      redirect_uri
    }))
})

app.get('/callback', async (req, res) => {
  const code = req.query.code
  axios.post('https://office.bexio.com/oauth/access_token', {

      grant_type: 'authorization_code',
      code: code,
      redirect_uri: redirect_uri,
      client_id: CLIENT_ID,
      client_secret: CLIENT_SECRET
  })
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response)
  })
  .catch(error =>{
    console.log(error)
  })
});
```

This is the http request:

```
 { url: 'https://office.bexio.com/oauth/access_token',
     method: 'post',
     data:
 '{"grant_type":"authorization_code",
"code":CODE,
"redirect_uri":"http://localhost:8888/callback",
"client_id":CLIENT_ID,
"client_secret":CLIENT_SECRET}',
     headers:
      { Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
        'User-Agent': 'axios/0.19.0',
        'Content-Length': 265 }
```

I expect an access token but I always get an 'invalid_client' error with the desription 'Client credentials were not found in the headers or body'

Answer (score 4):

You have to send the data to OAuth2 token endpoint in `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format. Axios defaults to `application/json`. You can see the documentation for using the format in here: https://github.com/axios/axios#using-applicationx-www-form-urlencoded-format. It would in your case be done like this:

```
const params = new URLSearchParams();
params.append('grant_type', 'authorization_code');
params.append('code', code);
params.append('redirect_uri', redirect_uri);
params.append('client_id', CLIENT_ID);
params.append('client_secret', CLIENT_SECRET);

axios.post('https://office.bexio.com/oauth/access_token', params)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that fixed the problem.

Comment: I love u man. I've been going through this for like 8 hours trying to figure it out. Thanks!